# I have the login session code after login on the menu bar if user is logged in it will show logout otherwise it shows login menu

Tags: php

But the problem is this code is working properly at local server but not working at online server. So can anybody help me in getting the problem?

login.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from users where email='$email' and pwd='$pwd'");
 $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

 if($result > 0) {
 session_register(email);
 session_register(pwd);

$_SESSION['unique_user_id'] = $result['id']; // store username
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']; // store username
$_SESSION['pwd'] = $_POST['pwd']; // store password

echo "<script>alert('Logged in Successfully');</script>";
header("location:index.php");

}
else {
$error = "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again";
}
}
?>

<form id="form" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Registered Email-id" onBlur="error(this.id,this.value),email_vali(this.id,this.value)">
                    <br>
                    <input id="pwd" name="pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" type="password" onBlur="error(this.id,this.value)">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="return login_check()">
                    <br>
                </form>
```

index.php (here i m checking the user is logined or not)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<?php  session_start();
 if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
 echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>';
} else {
echo '<li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>';
} ?>
</ul>
```

`

Comment: in `index.php`, you cannot output any HTML before calling `session_start()`. There is no way this is working on your local server without output buffering.

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) of `session_register()`: *"Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.*" - and you use it with constants, not variables or strings. Further, `$_SESSION['pwd']` this is really bad. As is anything `mysql_`, you should look into using `mysqli_` or PDO with prepared statements - specially if you're just getting into PHP! This seems like a very outdated tutorial you're following.

Comment: What do you mean by NOT WORKING , any error ? blank page ? exactly what ?what is happening after inputting username and password ?

Comment: I also called the session_start(); before HTML. But also getting the same problem.